# BitBucket OAuth integration into a Koa Node.js App

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, bitbucket, fetch-api

I'm making an app to fetch certain files from GitHub and BitBucket for easier reviews; and to learn BE a bit.
GitHub integration went without too many issues, but I'm stuck on BitBucket for the following reason.

I'm getting the following error when trying to make a POST request to BB OAuth to get their access token:
`DATA:  { error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Unsupported grant type: None' }`

This is the code block where I call BB OAuth:

```
const reqUrl = ctx.request.url;
const code = reqUrl.split('?query=')[1];
const tokenURL = 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token';
const params = {
  client_id: process.env.BITBUCKET_KEY,
  client_secret: process.env.BITBUCKET_SECRET,
  code,
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  redirect_uri: bitBucketRedirectURL
};
   
const response = await fetch(tokenURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  params: JSON.stringify(params),
} as any);
const data = await response.json();
console.log("DATA: ", data)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I've also tried changing the POST req headers from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; and I've tried changing the `grant_type` from `authorization_code` to `client_credentials`, but obviously, neither of those worked...